# Where can I find a release form for using clients' photos on websites and on promotional materials?

Tags: legal, model-releases

I am looking for a release form so I can use pictures I took of my clients on my website and on promotional material.

I have no intention of selling the photos.

I have no idea what to even google. Any suggestions?

Comment: Google 'Model Release Form' or simply include a clause saying something like 'The model agrees that the photographer can use any photographs taken in promotional material unless expressly informed otherwise'

Comment: And note that the form of release differs from jurisdiction to jurisdiction, so include your country/state in the search term. If your results include your national professional photographic association, that would be your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check these links, I have found them all useful in the past.

- http://asmp.org/tutorials/forms.html
- http://www.weddingphotographydirectory.com/wedding-photo/for-wedding-photographers/professional-articles/model-release-2.aspx
- http://www.acclaimimages.com/resources/index.html

(If you have a Getty account then you can just download theirs. The same may well go for other stock agencies.)

Edit: also check out this iPhone app, it looks excellent and the releases generated are accepted by Getty and Alamy: https://www.facebook.com/pages/VMRelease/105679776169458

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Canada, you might consider the [CAPIC release form templates](http://www.capic.org/resources.html?screen=forms).